# How to jump to a specific position in a track playing using SoundCloud API?

Tags: api, progress-bar, soundcloud, audio-player, soundmanager2

I am making a custom music player using SoundCloud API by using SoundManager2 and I want to incorporate a progress bar so that the user can jump to a specific point of the track.

I used the code:

```
currentTrack.setPosition(currentVal);
```

where currentVal is the track position where I want to jump to. But if the track is not loaded completely then the track doesn't jump to the correct position.

How do I jump to the position that I specify even when the song hasn't finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

When i understand you right, one way could be to use sm2s onload function.

Here is an example.

```
SC.stream("/tracks/148976759",{
     autoLoad: true,
     onload: function(){
         this.setPosition(15000);
         this.play();                        
         }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/9CAeU/

Answer (score 0):

```
soundManager.setPosition("sound.id",currentVal)
soundManager.play("sound.id");
```

This start playing at a specific position.